# OpenGL generate vertex attributes

Tags: opengl, webgl

I like to render several surfaces that are dynamically computed in a vertex shader. The surfaces are generated by displacement of vertices in a 2d or 3d grid that is stored in vertex attribute buffers.

However, if very large (millions of vertices) and many surfaces with different resolutions are rendered, I need to generate a lot of "boring" grid data that fills up memory, maybe slows down rendering and sometimes interrupt rendering if large new grids are generated.

Is there any way to generate simple vertex attributes grids on the fly, without the need of storing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can generate an uniform grid directly in the vertex shader. In reasonably modern GL, you can work completely *attribute-less*. The `gl_VertexID` input in the shader will tell you what vertex you are currently processing. With a little bit of integer division and modulo, you can easily map that to an 2D grid. You still need some way to describe the displacement. The intuitive way seems to be using a 2D texture for that (and you can easiliy derive the texcoords from the coords in the grid), but there are different options. You could even generate it procedurally by some mathematical model.

Comment: But which OpenGL call actually runs the thing then? Is it possible to use `glDrawArrays` without any array bound?

Comment: Give it a quick try in WebGL, just to find out WebGL doesn't expose `gl_VertexID` at all... So `gl_VertexID` doesn't seems to be supported by all OpenGL flavors, despite it's simplicity. I just add a tag WebGL now..

Comment: However, `gl_VertexID` can be emulated by an int array of course, and that can be reused for all cases with less primitves than it's size. So better then nothing I guiess...

Comment: @dronus: Well, you should have mentioned WebGL earlier... It is based on GLES2, and very limited in these regards. For webgl, I can't really come up with a good solution (which of course does not imply that there isn't one).

Comment: Yes, I put them all into a pot.. my mistake. For OpenGL it is already hard to say if some feature is available or not on certain setup, and GLES isn't even called OpenGL..

Comment: As there seem no equivalent to this working in GLES nor any alternative, I accept this answer.